# (Unity C#) Some methods can access a Stack, but some can't, leaving it blank

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, methods, stack

I have a bug in my Unity project and it doesn't make any sense to me why, simply putting it, I have a script with a Stack, which represents an Inventory slot, when you add a item to it, it pushes it into the correct inventory slot, as seem in this GIF: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Hac.jpg

In the left is the inventory, in the right is just a Box with random items. My problem started with trying to make a hoveover tooltip to remove items from the inventory. Here is the script of the slots.

```
    public class InvSlots : MonoBehaviour , IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
    {

        public Stack<Item> items = new Stack<Item>();

        public Text stackTxt;

        public Image imgItem;

        public GameObject ToolTip, Exclude;


        public bool IsEmpty
        {
            get { if (items == null) { return true; } return items.Count == 0; }
        }

        public int CountItem()
        {
            return this.items.Count;
        }


        public Item CurrentItem
        {

            get { return items.Peek(); }

        }

        public bool isAvailable
        {

            get { return CurrentItem.maxnumber > items.Count; }

        }

        public void addItem(Item item)
        {
            items.Push(item);
            changeSprite(Resources.Load<Sprite>("imgs/ItemIcons/" + item.iconPath));
            if (items.Count >= 1)
            {
                stackTxt.text = items.Count.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void changeSprite(Sprite sprite)
        {
            imgItem.sprite = sprite;
            imgItem.color = new Vector4(1, 1, 1, 1);
        }


     public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("pointer enter " + items.Peek().nome);
        if (items.Count > 0)
        {
            Instantiate(ToolTip, gameObject.transform.position, new Quaternion(), GameObject.Find("BGInv").transform);
            GameObject.Find("ToolTipNome").GetComponent<TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI>().text = CurrentItem.nome;
            GameObject.Find("ToolTipDesc").GetComponent<TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI>().text = CurrentItem.desc;
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("pointer exit" + items.Peek().nome);
        if (items.Count > 0)
        {
            Destroy(GameObject.Find("HoverOver Tooltip 1(Clone)"));
        }
    }

    public void OpenExclude()
    {
        Debug.Log("Open Exclude " + items.Peek().nome);
        if (items.Count > 0)
        {
            Destroy(GameObject.Find("HoverOver Tooltip 1(Clone)"));
            Instantiate(Exclude, gameObject.transform.position, new Quaternion(), GameObject.Find("BGInv").transform);
        }

    }

    public void CloseExclude()
    {
        Debug.Log("Close exclude " + items.Peek().nome);
        if (items.Count > 0)
        {
            Destroy(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ExcludeItems"));
        }
    }

    public void ExcludeOneItem()
    {
        Debug.Log("Exclude 1 " + items.Peek().nome);
        if (items.Count > 0)
        {
            items.Pop();
            stackTxt.text = items.Count.ToString();
            Destroy(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ExcludeItems"));
        }
    }

    public void ExcludeAllItem()
    {
        Debug.Log("Exclude all " + items.Peek().nome);
        if (items.Count > 0)
        {
            imgItem.color = new Vector4(1, 1, 1, 1);
            items.Clear();
            stackTxt.text = "";
            Destroy(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ExcludeItems"));
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, I have that Stack of items, BUT whenever I try to access the Stack through the methods CloseExclude(), ExcludeOneItem() and ExcludeAllItem() the Stack is empty, but in every other method of the script the Stack have items like it should. I have no idea why something like that is happening, i've never seen anything like this. Just to keep it clear, this methods are being called from the OnClick of the buttons, but so is the OpenExclude() so I don't think that's it.
As you can see in the script, I have a bunch of Logs, Here is a picture of the console:
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HcYt.png)

And a GIF to help you guys see it more clearly:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYBBU.jpg

TLDR I have a stack that is not working on certain methods of my script, but works fine in others.

Comment: Why does you error count goes from 3 to 9 suddenly without calling any function in the gif?

Comment: My mouse is hovering over slots without any items, and since my script have a log trying to show the name of the item, he gets all those errors

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/852155/invalidoperationexception-operation-is-not-valid-d-1.html)

Comment: I did, yes, but I don't think it's the same problem, this one seems to be having problems with the UI in general, mine is mostly working tho

Comment: It seems your little context menu there (or the buttons with their handlers within) work on a different, separate _InvSlots_ instance...

Comment: Do you mean the one with the remove buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [elgozo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2819245/elgonzo) I managed to get it right, the prefab of the exclude menu was getting the wrong InvSlots Instance indeed! What I did was simply make a script to set the InvSlots that the prefab is using when it gets instantiated, so it doesn't mess it up.